# What does "[it] was not an option" mean, exactly?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the following phrase:

> A romantic relationship between X and Z was never an option.

Does it mean that it was not feasible due to past circumstances or not desirable  by one of the two and thus not chosen  ?

Comment: Impossible to say without more context. It could be said by a writer about two characters in their book, meaning that that author feels such a relationship would have clashed with the main story line they had in mind for the book. It could mean that X and Z never were attracted to each other. It could mean that X and Z were culturally prohibited from forming such a relationship. But all we know from what you give us is exactly what it means: such a relationship could not have happened.

Comment: definitely need more context for this. it could "not be an option" for many reasons, which would be both too numerous to list and wild guesses

Comment: The exact text is " A romantic relationship between you and I was never an option."  Translating this gives me a hard time as there are several interpretations to this phrase.

Comment: We still need more context. What is the relationship between the people, what is their past like? Only with that information can we fill in the specific meaning of "not an option".

Comment: If I decide something is not an option, I am saying no to the idea (Not up for discussion, off the table, not yours to choose), Before translating, remove the idiom of 'option' and use 'a possibility' or 'a consideration.' Also, better to say 'between you and me' not 'you and I.'

Comment: Actually I have to translate this idiom into Greek. So I am trying to understand if this phrase  " A romantic relationship between us was never a option" means " it's something I would never choose even if I had the opportunity" or " it was not an option due to other inhibiting factors.

Comment: @Kika Do you want to translate it into a specific idiomatic Greek sentence, or do you just want to convey the meaning? The English idiom does not imply any reasons, it comes close to _δεν υπάρχει περίπτωση που θα ειχαμε σχέση_ or _με τίποτα θα ειχαμε σχέση εμείς_

Comment: @oerkelens I would like to convey the meaning. For instance would this expression be used to reject someone ?

Comment: @Kika: but there is not "deeper" meaning. It can be used to reject someone, but it can also be used to express regret about that relation never happening. You cannot translate one of many possible interpretations of this sentence and claim it is correct. You need more context for that. Lacking context, you should not add connotations that are not associated with the original, so on its own you should look for a neutral translation that just conveys the meaning that such a relationship would or could never have happened, without implying reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a difference between the two sentences:

> A romantic relationship between X and Z was **not** an option.

This means that *at the time* the sentence refers to one could not count on X and Z developing a romantic relationship.

> A romantic relationship between X and Z was **never** an option.

This means that those who may have expected X and Z to develop a romantic relationship should not have expected it - ever.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the relationship is not possible due to past circumstances. It would not have  worked out even if they came into one due to inhibiting reasons.